# Oracle Select query dynamic parameter condition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Help me write the select query

I have 3 tables as follows

```
Subscriber
############################

Subscr_id   parent id
---------   ---------
1            100
2            100
3            101
4            101
```

so there can be more than one subscr_id under one parent id (these are called locations).  Other tables are

```
Products
############################

Subscr_id   products   businessline
---------   --------   -------------
1            5100       100
1            1100       200
2            3100       300
```

and

```
Addons
############################

Subscr_id   products   businessline  addons
---------   ---------  ------------  ------
1            5100       100            1
1            5100       100            5
1            5100       100            30
1            1100       200            5
1            1100       200            25
```

Now I have four parameters -1) products 2) businessline 3) addons  4) parent id which users will give. but none of  1,2,3  is mandatory.

For the input parent id I will output true else false based on the following conditions

1. if only product is given then result will be true if one of the locations of the parent have entries with products = given product input
2. if only business is given then result will be true if one of the locations of the parent have entries with businessline = given business line
3. if both business and product is given then result will be true if one of the locations of the parent have entries with businessline = given business line and product = given product
4. if only addons is given then result will be true if one of the locations of the parent have entries with addons = given addon in the Addons tables
   like this numerous conditions are possible

I want to write a single select query

Comment: For future reference, you should *edit your question* not edit other people's answers. I mean, I even told you to edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

i had tried in my local database based on the on your data. the procedure is as follows
in the following procedure i used some notations they are

- Subscr_id as sid
- parent id as pid
- businessline  as bl
- products as pro

  ```
  declare 
  given_pro number(5):=&given_pro;
  given_bl number(5):=&given_bl;
  given_addons number(5):=&given_addons;
  as 
  cursor cur is 
  select distinct S.PID from subscriber s,product p,addons a where 
  (nvl(given_pro,1)=given_pro and nvl(given_bl,1)=1 and S.SID=P.SID and A.PRO=given_pro and p.pro=given_pro and A.PRO=P.PRO and A.SID=S.SID and P.SID=A.SID)
  or
  (nvl(given_bl,1)=given_bl and nvl(given_pro,1)=1 and A.BL=given_bl and p.bl=given_bl and S.SID=P.SID and A.BL=P.BL and A.SID=S.SID and P.SID=A.SID)
  or
  (nvl(given_bl,1)=given_bl and nvl(given_pro,1)=given_pro and A.PRO=given_pro and p.pro=given_pro and A.BL=given_bl and p.bl=given_bl and S.SID=P.SID and A.PRO=P.PRO and A.BL=P.BL and A.SID=S.SID and P.SID=A.SID)
  or
  (nvl(given_addons,1)=given_addons and nvl(given_bl,1)=1 and nvl(given_pro,1)=1 and A.SID=S.SID);
  rec cur%rowtype;
  begin
  open cur;
  loop 
  fetch cur into rec;
  exit when cur%notfound;
  dbms_output.put_line(rec.pid ||'  hello');
  end loop;
  close cur;
  end;
  ```

this procedure will give you only pid

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a lot of detail regarding implementation so:

1. Presuming you can have Subscribers with Products and Products without Addons I have used outer joins for those tables
2. I have used a sub-query to pass in the parameter values, as it is the easiest way of testing the combinations in [the inevitable SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a1bea/16).

So here is a solution which implements the four conditions you specify in the question, plus a bonus of (`products` + `businessline` + `addons`).

```
with cte as (select sub.*
                    , prod.products
                    , prod.businessline
                    , adds.addons
             from subscriber sub
                  left outer join products prod
                        on prod.Subscr_id = sub.Subscr_id
                  left outer join addons adds
                        on adds.Subscr_id = prod.Subscr_id
                           and adds.products = prod.products
                           and adds.businessline = prod.businessline
           )
    , params as ( select 100 as par_id
                         , 1100 as prod_id
                         , 200 as bus_id
                         , null as add_id
                   from dual )
select cte.* 
from cte
     cross join params
where cte.parent_id = params.par_id
and ( 
  (params.prod_id = cte.products and params.bus_id is null and params.add_id is null)
  or (params.prod_id is null and params.bus_id = cte.businessline and params.add_id is null)
  or (params.prod_id = cte.products and params.bus_id = cte.businessline and params.add_id is null)
  or (params.prod_id is null and params.bus_id is null and params.add_id = cte.addons)
  or (params.prod_id = cte.products and params.bus_id = cte.businessline and params.add_id = cte.addons)
  )
order by cte.subscr_id, cte.products, cte.businessline, cte.addons
/
```

If this does not do want you want please *edit your question* and clarify your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the query according to the requirement

```sql
with cte as (select sub.*
                    , prod.prod_code
                    , prod.bus_line_code
                    , adds.add_on_code
             from subscriber sub
                  left outer join subscriber_bl_product prod
                        on prod.Subscr_id = sub.Subsr_id
                  left outer join subscriber_bl_product_add_on  adds
                        on adds.Subscr_id = prod.Subscr_id
                           and adds.prod_code = prod.prod_code
                           and adds.bus_line_code = prod.bus_line_code
           )
    , params as ( select 100 as par_id
                         , null as prod_id
                         , null as bus_id
                         , 100 as add_id
                   from dual )

select distinct cte.parent_id 
from cte
     cross join params
where cte.parent_id = params.par_id 
and ( 
  (params.prod_id = cte.prod_code and params.bus_id is null and params.add_id is null)
  or (params.prod_id is null and params.bus_id = cte.bus_line_code and params.add_id is null)
  or (params.prod_id = cte.prod_code and params.bus_id = cte.bus_line_code and params.add_id is null)
  or (params.prod_id is null and params.bus_id is null and params.add_id = cte.add_on_code)
  or (params.prod_id = cte.prod_Code and params.bus_id = cte.bus_line_code and params.add_id = cte.add_on_code)
  )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using dynamic sql

THanks for your answers . It really helped me a lot :)

```
declare
v_prod number(8) := 22  ;
v_bus number(8) := 01 ;
v_add number(8) := 6666666;
v_add_stat varchar2(1):= 'T';
v_sql varchar2(32767);
begin
v_sql := 'select * from
subscriber where subsr_id = :parent and exists (select * from '|| (case when v_add  is not null or v_add_stat is not null  then ' subscriber_bl_product_add_on ' else 'subscriber_bl_product' end )
||' where subscr_id in (select subsr_id from subscriber where parent_id = :parent ) '
||case when v_prod is not null then 'and prod_code = '||v_prod  else '' end|| case when v_bus is not null then  ' and bus_line_code = '||v_bus  else  ''  end ||case when v_add is not null then ' and add_on_code = '||v_add  else '' end ||case when v_add_stat is not null then ' and add_on_Stat_ind = ''' ||v_add_stat||'''' else '' end ||')';
dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
execute immediate v_sql;
end;
```